# Queueable Apex - You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out

Tags: salesforce, apex

We have an issue with queueable apex. Great if you could help on this?

Their requirement is to sync Salesforce object to external system.

Currently there is a trigger that executes an queueable apex job that do the call-out and update lead at the end.

This works perfectly during our testing. Also we have bulk tested today. However randomly we get the following error.

I will share a sample code.

Error:
1:  Lead Id: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX Error : System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling outType: System.CalloutException
Cause: null
Message: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out

We only do updates at the end of queue execution. This works perfectly when we test for single or bulk load. Issue is intermittent.

```
trigger TRIG_Lead on Lead (before insert, before update, after update, after insert) {
if (Trigger.isAfter) {
    if (Trigger.isInsert) {
        TRIG_Lead_Handler.afterInsert(Trigger.newMap);
    }
    if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
        TRIG_Lead_Handler.afterUpdate(Trigger.oldMap, Trigger.newMap);
    }
}
```

}

public without sharing class TRIG_Lead_Handler {

```
// A method that will be called by trigger in case of an after insert event
public static void afterInsert(Map<Id, Lead> newMap) {
    Map<Id, Lead> optimusLeads = new Map<Id, Lead>();
    System.debug('After insert trigger');

    // Looping through all leads
    for (Id leadId : newMap.keySet()) {
        Lead newLead = newMap.get(leadId);
        if (newLead.Optimus_Push_Criteria__c
                && newLead.Optimus_External_Id__c == null
                && newLead.Optimus_Push_Scheduled__c
                && !OptimusService.leadScheduledSet.contains(leadId)) {
            OptimusService.leadScheduledSet.add(leadId); // to prevent recursive pushes
            optimusLeads.put(leadId, newLead);
        }
    }

    if (!optimusLeads.isEmpty()) {
        System.enqueueJob(new QuableOptimusService('INSERT', optimusLeads.keySet()));
    }

}
public static void afterUpdate(Map<Id, Lead> oldMap, Map<Id, Lead> newMap) {
    Map<Id, Lead> convertedLeads = new Map<Id, Lead>();
    Map<Id, Lead> optimusLeads = new Map<Id, Lead>();
    // Looping through all leads
    for (Id leadId : newMap.keySet()) {
        // Declaring 2 variables: oldLead and newLead.
        // They represent the same lead before and after the update respectively
        Lead oldLead = oldMap.get(leadId);
        Lead newLead = newMap.get(leadId);

        if (newLead.isConverted) { 
            convertedLeads.put(leadId, newLead);
        }

        if (newLead.Optimus_Push_Criteria__c
                && newLead.Optimus_External_Id__c == null
                && newLead.Optimus_Push_Scheduled__c && !oldLead.Optimus_Push_Scheduled__c
                && !OptimusService.leadScheduledSet.contains(leadId)) {

            OptimusService.leadScheduledSet.add(leadId); // to prevent recursive pushes
            optimusLeads.put(leadId, newLead);
        }
    }

    if (!convertedLeads.isEmpty()) {
        reparentFeedItemsToConvertedOpportunity(convertedLeads);
    }

    if (!optimusLeads.isEmpty()) {
        System.enqueueJob(new QuableOptimusService('INSERT', optimusLeads.keySet()));
    }
}
```

}

public with sharing class QuableOptimusService implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {

```
String dmlType;
Lead currentProcessedLead;
Set<Id> IdSet;
List<Lead> leadList = new List<Lead>();
Set<Id> syncedIdSet = new Set<Id>();

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public QuableOptimusService( String dType, Set<Id> IdSet ) {
    this.dmlType = dType;
this.IdSet = IdSet;
}

public void execute(QueueableContext context) {

    // Query all the fields required for the service
    leadList = [ SELECT Id, Street, PostalCode, City, CreatedDate, Email, Status, Salutation, FirstName, LastName,
            Phone, BP_Number__c, MobilePhone, Deal_Comments__c, Degree_of_urgency__c, Housing__c, Language__c,
            Lead_Sources_EDF__c, Lead_Sources_Subtypes_EDF__c, Lead_Type__c, Net__c, Name_of_Sales_person__c,
            Number_of_Panels__c, Opt_out_communication_PV__c, Payback_Timeframe_in_years__c, Picture__c,
            Product_Interest__c, Region_in_Belgium__c, Total_earnings_over_time_horizon__c, Type_of_Web_lead__c,
            VAT_Number__c, Sales_Partner__c, Seller_ID__c, Shop_Location__c, Promocode__c, RecordTypeId,
            Company, Saving_in__c, Cell_Phone__c, Optimus_External_Id__c
    FROM Lead
    WHERE Id IN : IdSet AND Optimus_External_Id__c = null ];

    List<Lead> leadsToUpdate = new List<Lead>();
    OptimusService os = new OptimusService();

    try{

        Integer i = 0;
        for (Lead s : leadList) {
            currentProcessedLead = (Lead) s;

            if (dmlType != null && dmlType.equalsIgnoreCase('INSERT')) {
                currentProcessedLead.Optimus_External_Id__c = os.doLeadCreate(currentProcessedLead);

                if(currentProcessedLead.Optimus_External_Id__c != null){
                    leadsToUpdate.add(currentProcessedLead);
                }
            } else if (dmlType != null && dmlType.equalsIgnoreCase('UPDATE')) {
                os.doLeadUpdate(currentProcessedLead);
            }

            // Add Synced Lead Ids
            syncedIdSet.add(s.Id);
            if (++i == 80) {
                break;
            }
        }
        // remove synced lead Ids and enqueue again
        IdSet.removeAll(syncedIdSet);
        if (!IdSet.isEmpty()) {
            System.enqueueJob(new QuableOptimusService(dmlType, IdSet));
        }


        update leadsToUpdate;

    } Catch( Exception e) {
        System.debug('Error :' +e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

}

public class OptimusService {

```
public String doLeadCreate(Lead l) {
    system.debug('*** LEAD CREATE');
    // login if needed
    if (Test.isRunningTest()) accessToken = 'abc';
    if (accessToken == null) {
        doLogin();
    }
    // headers
    Map<String, String> headers = New Map<String, String>{
        'cache-control' => 'no-cache',
        'content-type' => 'application/json',
        'fm-data-token' => accessToken
    };
    // body
    String body = generateLeadJSON(l);
    System.debug('--body--' +body);
    // request
    HttpRequest req = buildRequest(RECORD_URL + '/' + API_LAYOUT + '/', headers, body);
    System.debug('--req--' +req);
    // response
    HttpResponse res = sendRequest(req);
    if (res.getStatusCode() != 200) {
        throw new OptimusException('Received error from Optimus Lead Create Webservice: '
            + res.getStatusCode() + ': ' + res.getStatus());
    } else {
        LeadCreateResponse lcr = handleLeadCreateResponse(res.getBody());
        if (lcr != null && lcr.recordId != null) {
            return lcr.recordId;
        } else{
            throw new OptimusException('Lead create response null : '
                    + res.getStatusCode() + ': ' + res.getStatus());
        }
    }
}

public void doLeadUpdate(Lead l) {
    system.debug('*** LEAD UPDATE');
    // login if needed
    if (Test.isRunningTest()) accessToken = 'abc';
    if (accessToken == null) {
        doLogin();
    }

    // headers
    Map<String, String> headers = New Map<String, String>{
        'cache-control' => 'no-cache',
        'content-type' => 'application/json',
        'fm-data-token' => accessToken
    };
    // body
    String body = generateLeadJSON(l);
    System.debug('--body--' +body);
    // request
    HttpRequest req = buildRequest(RECORD_URL + '/' + API_LAYOUT + '/' + l.Optimus_External_Id__c, headers, body);
    System.debug('--req--' +req);
    // response
    HttpResponse res = sendRequest(req);
    if (res.getStatusCode() != 200) {
        throw new OptimusException('Received error from Optimus Lead Update Webservice: '
            + res.getStatusCode() + ': ' + res.getStatus());
    }
}


@TestVisible
private void doLogin() {
    system.debug('*** LOGIN');
    // headers
    Map<String, String> headers = New Map<String, String>{
        'cache-control' => 'no-cache',
        'content-type' => 'application/json'
    };
    // body
    String body = generateLoginJSON();
    // request
    HttpRequest req = buildRequest(AUTH_URL, headers, body);
    // response
    HttpResponse res = sendRequest(req);
    if (res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
        LoginResponse logres = handleLoginResponse(res.getBody());
        this.accessToken = logres.token;
    } else {
        throw new OptimusException('Received error from Optimus Login Webservice'
            + res.getStatusCode() + ': ' + res.getStatus());
    }
}


private HttpRequest buildRequest(String url, Map<String, String> headers, String body) {
    // Instantiate a new HTTP request
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

    // Set method and endpoint
    req.setEndpoint(url);
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setTimeout(120000);

    // Set headers
    if (headers != null) {
        for (String key : headers.keySet()) {
            req.setHeader(key, headers.get(key));
        }
    }

    // Set body
    if (body != null && body.length() > 0) {
        req.setBody(body);
    }

    system.debug('*** req: ' + req);
    system.debug('*** req.body: ' + req.getBody());
    return req;
}

private HttpResponse sendRequest(HttpRequest req) {
    // Send HTTP request and get HTTP response
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpResponse res = http.send(req);

    system.debug('*** res.status: ' + res.getStatus());
    system.debug('*** res.statuscode: ' + res.getStatusCode());
    system.debug('*** res.body: ' + res.getBody());

    return res;
}
```

}

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

This is addressed on [Salesforce Stackexchange here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/203070/uncommitted-work-pending-in-unit-test-with-trigger-and-queueable-callout)

Basically, you have to gate your enqueueing in a test context

Comment: The post you linked to really doesn't illustrate what the issue is at hand, and doesn't give the OP a clear path to solving the issue.